# Postgresql full-text-search on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, heroku

Hello I want to use full-text search using postrgresql but the problem on heroku, i can not think of a way to have custom dictionary using my language (Greek).

on my pc I did

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY greek_ispell (
TEMPLATE = ispell,
DictFile = greek,
AffFile = greek,
StopWords = greek
);
```

and setup the sharedir using the custom dictionaries. Is there a way to do this on heroku?

Comment: Maybe I could somehow include the dict/aff files inside the database?

Comment: George did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Im sorry for the late reply. No sorry i did not come back with anything. I just used some little tricks but used the default dictionary using full text search.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Texticle](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/10/17/full-text-search-on-heroku/), it's free full-text search on Postgres (so it works on Heroku).

Comment: That does not solve the problem. The question was about using custom dictionary on postgres(heroku) for full-text search.